# asymptotic expansion for Bessel function $I_0(z)$ in terms of Gauss hypergeometric functions ${}_2F_1$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

On the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms) page  one can asympotoic formula of the Bessel function

$$ I_0(z) \propto \frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} $$

On the [Wolfram page](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/06/02/01/01/01/) there is a more detailed asymptotic formula for the Bessel functions

$$ I_0(z) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi z}} 
\left[ e^z \,{}_2F_0(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2};; \tfrac{1}{2z})+
 i \, e^{-z}\,{}_2F_0(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2};; -\tfrac{1}{2z}) \right] $$

I don't know much about hypergeometric functions except for this identity:

$$ {}_2F_1(a,b,c; z) = \int_0^1 x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a} \, dx$$

Is it possible to re-write the above asymptotic in terms of [Gauss hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) instead of [generalized hypergeometric functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16)?

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155273/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic don't mind me.  Peter showed me his paper in the summer.  I have been treating it as a crash course in special functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to rewrite the above asymptotic in terms of Gauss hypergeometric function $_2F_1$ because it is a degenerative form : The series representation of $_2F_0(a,b,x)$  is a divergent hypergeometric series. However, for $x < 0$  we have $$_2F_0(a,b,x) = \left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)^a U(a,1+a-b,-1/x)$$
where $U$ is the symbol for the confluent hypergeometric function, also known as Tricomi function. 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html

So, you can rewrite the asymptotic series in terms of confluent hypergeometric functions:
$$_2F_0\left(\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2z}\right) = (-2z)^{\frac{1}{2}}\: U\left(\frac{1}{2},1,-2z\right)$$